Keycloak log-out issue in Cypress on MacOs
I am using cypress for e2e and cypress-keycloak npm package to sign-in and sign-out in my e2e tests. On MacOs I have an issue when I'm log-out. I use this command to log-out
cy.logout({
root: Cypress.env('keycloackAuthUrl'),
realm: Cypress.env('keycloakRealm'),
redirect_uri: Cypress.env('redirectUrl'),

});
https:///auth/realms/ats/protocol/openid-connect/logout/logout-confirm?client_id=account&tab_id=MUEbAVCZe6E
returns 400 error and that causes tests failing. On Windows works fine. Any ideas how to fix it?
